# Why does a system update ask for my password?

Tags: 14.04, password, update-manager

If doing updates is safe and secure, why does it need my password?

From what I have read so far, it prevents man-in-the-middle attacks also. So what vulnerabilities exists that a user should be aware of?

Comment: What is your question about? What are you trying to do? What "update" are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, most updates don't ask for a password. The system is able to update the necessary files without extra permissions.

When it does ask for your password, it's to send to `sudo`, which lets you run a command with root permissions. There are some files that can't be modified except with root permissions, such as the kernel. When one of these has an update, you need to authenticate to allow the system to update those files.

Comment: that makes sense. thanx!